# Recursive Function Not Returning Value

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

This code is supposed to find the sum of the digits of an integer. When I run it, the computer just processes for a while and then nothing happens

```
def sum_of_digits(integer):
    numlist = list(str(integer))
    if len(numlist) == 0:
        result = 0
    elif len(numlist) == 1:
        result = numlist[0]
    else:
        midPoint = len(numlist) // 2
        result = sum_of_digits(numlist[:midPoint]) + 
        sum_of_digits(numlist[midPoint:])
    print(result)
    return result


sum_of_digits(123456)
```

Comment: Can you fix your indentation? It looks like you are printing `result` after returning from the function.

Comment: You should make clear  what do you mean by `nothing happens`. e.g. No print out at all? How did you call your `sum_of_digits`?

Comment: 1st, instead of assigning to result, you need to return the value directly in each if condition closure. 2nd, your sum_of_digits defined to take integer as argument, but take a list as argument within the last else closure. Function needs to have consistent argument's data type

Answer (score 1):

This answer does **not** convert the number to a string (or other iterable) and then back to a number.

```
def sum_of_digits (n: int, sum = 0) -> int:
  if n < 10:
    return n + sum
  else:
    return sum_of_digits (n // 10, sum + n % 10)

print(sum_of_digits(1))      # 1
print(sum_of_digits(12))     # 3
print(sum_of_digits(123))    # 6
print(sum_of_digits(1234))   # 10
print(sum_of_digits(12345))  # 15
```

Answer (score 1):

Another simple solution without data type conversion:

```
def sum_of_digits(integer):
    if integer == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return integer % 10 + sum_of_digits(integer // 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

You've horridly confused your data types.  Naming something `integer` does not make it an integer.  You're fine on the first call.  Had you done any rudimentary debugging, you'd have seen the problem: you turn the integer into a list of single-character strings.

When you split the list and recur, you pass that half-list into your function as `integer`.  When you immediately turn it into a new string with `str(integer)`, you get a string something like `"['1']"`, rather than a simple character digit.  When you explode *that* into a list, you get `['[', "'", '1', ']', "'"]` as `numlist` ... and it's a nasty infinite recursion from there.

First, make sure you have a consistent interface for your function: if nothing else, reconstitute the half-string into an integer and feed that value to your recursive call.  Second, don't get overly expansive: you can simply convert the integer to a string and work on the individual digits; no need to make a list from that.
Third, see this lovely [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog for help.

Finally, you might research other solutions on line.  This is a common exercise.  I'm not telling you to copy the program -- but now that you've given the problem a good attempt, you can learn about the internal processing from others.

To get you moving, here's how I instrumented your code for debugging: `print` useful things on enter and exit, and put in a delay (sleep) so I have a chance to interrupt the program before useful info rolls off the screen.

```
from time import sleep

call = 0

def sum_of_digits(integer):
    global call

    call += 1
    id = call 

    print("ENTER", call, integer)

    numlist = list(str(integer))
    print("numlist", numlist)
    sleep(1)

    if len(numlist) == 0: 
        result = 0
    elif len(numlist) == 1:
        result = numlist[0]
    else:
        midPoint = len(numlist) // 2
        result = sum_of_digits(numlist[:midPoint]) + \ 
                 sum_of_digits(numlist[midPoint:])

    print("LEAVE", id, result)
    return result


test = [0, 1, 12]
for case in test:
    call = 0
    sum_of_digits(case)
    print("-------------------------")
```

Output:

```
ENTER 1 0
numlist ['0']
LEAVE 1 0
-------------------------
ENTER 1 1
numlist ['1']
LEAVE 1 1
-------------------------
ENTER 1 12
numlist ['1', '2']
ENTER 2 ['1']
numlist ['[', "'", '1', "'", ']']
ENTER 3 ['[', "'"]
numlist ['[', "'", '[', "'", ',', ' ', '"', "'", '"', ']']
ENTER 4 ['[', "'", '[', "'", ',']
numlist ['[', "'", '[', "'", ',', ' ', '"', "'", '"', ',', ' ', "'", '[', "'", ',', ' ', '"', "'", '"', ',', ' ', "'", ',', "'", ']']
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "so.py", line 33, in <module>
    sum_of_digits(case)
  File "so.py", line 23, in sum_of_digits
    result = sum_of_digits(numlist[:midPoint]) + \
  File "so.py", line 23, in sum_of_digits
    result = sum_of_digits(numlist[:midPoint]) + \
  File "so.py", line 23, in sum_of_digits
    result = sum_of_digits(numlist[:midPoint]) + \
  File "so.py", line 15, in sum_of_digits
    sleep(1)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling your own function inside of itself. Also when you are calling it you are giving it a list instead of an integer so are causing it to iterate over a list instead of the number that you want. You might want to use a `''.join` to return a integer instead of a list.

```
sum_of_digits(int(''.join(numlist[:midPoint]))))
```

Even If you do this there is still more work needed to be done to your function and you might want to use `int()` declarations to make sure you are working with integers.

Also you could use something that uses a for loop which would accomplish your goal in a more efficient manner but may not be what you are looking for.

```
def sum_of_digits(integer):
    ans=0
    for i in str(integer):
        ans+=int(i) 
    return ans
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though "nothing happens" doesn't give much info, you are clearly mixing data types in a really messy way.

Your `sum_of_digits` function takes an integer as a parameter, calling it `integer` doesn't make it one, it is still upon you to make sure you are calling it with the correct parameter.

When you call it recursively with `sum_of_digits(numlist[:midPoint])` and `sum_of_digits(numlist[midPoint:])` you are passing a string not an integer, and that's where things go wrong, work on that.